# How to run Netbeans IDE Java Desktop Application from command line

Tags: java, command-line

I have created a Java desktop application and I want to run it from the command line. How should I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way as you would run any other Java application from the command line. Depending on how it's packaged,

```
java -cp <classpath> fully.qualified.class.name
```

or

```
java -cp <classpath> -jar myapp.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

also.. when you right click on your project and say clean and build you should get something like this

> To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
>   java -jar "/home/nico/Workspace/testApplication1/dist/testApplication1.jar"

in the output window :)